# Как написать условие для такой задачи?

Tags: python, массивы

[image: Задача]

Ввел массив из 9 элементов, для каждой цифры по элементу.
При попытке деления какого либо числа например 832, отрываем старшую цифру, то есть 8 и записываем в нужный элемент, то есть 8 элемент будет равен 1, еще одно число - 845, элемент будет равен 2 и т.д
Не получается изменить значение элемента массива

```
n=int(input())
a=[0] * 9

for i in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    while x > 9:
        x // 10
        if x < 10:
            a[x-1] += 1

print(a)
```

Comment: Отредактируйте нормально код и приведите условие задачи текстом с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145223/edit).

Comment: Список первых цифр - `first_digits = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x)[0]), numbers))`, словарь встречаемостей `collections.Counter(first_digits)`.

Answer (score 1):

Так то всё работает, просто вы когда делили x на 10 не присвоили никуда результат операции `x // 10`.

```
n=int(input())
a=[0] * 9

for i in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    while x > 9:
        x //= 10 # здесь забыли присвоить результат, я исправил
        if x < 10:
            a[x-1] += 1

print(a)
```

А вообще можно сделать чуть короче, учитывая, что условие уже проверено в `while`.

```
n=int(input())
a=[0] * 9

for i in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    while x > 9:
        x //= 10
    a[x-1] += 1

print(a)
```

P.S. А, там ещё дальше сама задача, собственно. Она решается, например, так:

```
print(min([x for x in enumerate(a,1) if x[1] > 0], key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, теперь интересно разобраться в последней строке

Comment: @user395366 Попробуйте разобраться сами по шагам. Посмотрите что такое: 1) enumerate, 2) list comprehension (и как в них использовать if), 3) lambda, 4) как сортировать, искать min, max и т.д. используя свою функцию в качестве ключа

Comment: еще раз спасибо